# Помогите по htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Помогите написать .htaccess-файл такого содержания:

```
ЕСЛИ расширение файла = .png И файл лежит в папке "content"
 ТО ЕСЛИ существует файл имя_файла + _watemark_ + (имя домена из referer) ТО отдать его
 ИНАЧЕ отдать watemark.php?img=ИМЯ_ФАЙЛА
```

Comment: Я не вижу связи с .htaccess и с отдачей файла средствами php.

Comment:     Все пути для папки content к файлам png преобразовать в имя_файла_watermark_имя_домена, а в случае отсутствия такого файла отдать watermark.php?img=имя_файла
    
    Я правильно задачу понял?

Comment: Да. Единственное, путь такой: images/%itemID%/content, но, кроме content, есть еще другие папки (thumbs, icons, etc.) В каждую папку ID .htaccess не положишь, поэтому он должен находиться в images, но проверять только изображения из %itemID%/content.